# Playing audio from a playlist in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plyr

Radio playlist Using plyr-react module
Data from an API json file, get the data as a playlist and load it into the Plyr Audio player.

Trying to figure out how the url can be passed to the Plyr source path. Cant get the source url loaded into the Audio player.       Following is the code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Radioplyr from 'plyr-react';

const tracks = {
    type: "audio",
    sources: [
      {
        src: "https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/Kishi_Bashi_-_It_All_Began_With_a_Burst.mp3",
      },
      {
        src: "http://172.105.50.82/radio/8000/radio.mp3",
      },
      
    ]
  };
const audioSrc =  {
  type: "audio",
  sources: [
    {
      src: {playlist},
    },
    
  ]
};
return (
  <div>
    <Radioplyr source={audioSrc} />
    {playlist} 
    <ul className="playlist">
        {tracks.sources.map((item, i) => {
          return <li key={i}><a onClick={() => setPlaylist(item.src)}>{item.src}</a></li>
        })}
      </ul>
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use useState for current Track Source

```
const [currentTrackSrc, setCurrentTrackSrc] = useState(tracks.sources[0])

const [audioSrc, setAudioSrc]=  useState({
  type: "audio",
  sources: [
    {
      title: currentTrackSrc.title,
      src: currentTrackSrc.src,
    },
    
  ]
});
const changeOnDemandSong = (newSong, newSongTitle) => {
  setCurrentTrackSrc(newSong);
  setAudioSrc({
    type: "audio",
    sources: [
      {
        title: newSongTitle,
        src: newSong,
      },
    ]
  });
}
```

Onclick event changeOnDemandsong

```
<div className="">{audioSrc.sources[0].title}</div>
<ul className="ondemand-plList">
        {tracks.sources.map((item, i) => {
          return <li key={i} className="plItem"><a href="#!" onClick={() => { changeOnDemandSong(item.src, item.title); } }>{item.title}</a></li>
        })}
</ul>
```